# Yahoo email account hacked on iPad2

Tags: security, ipad

This has happened several times. I have changed my passwords and it's still being hacked. This happened when I was in England and also in Santa Barbara,  sending out messages, deleting sent messages.  Is this a Yahoo thing or is it something that can be fixed? How to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the yahoo account from your iPad to rule it out as a cause of your loss of control over the account. You'll probably need to work within Yahoo's password reset / linked account controls since it's almost certainly something you'll need to reset things on the server end to prevent.

Also, signing out of all computers might be good since they are more likely to have a virus or trojan than iOS.

Comment: thank for your insight. Is it unsafe to use iPad2 to email? I saw that yahoo has been having problems being hacked. Not sure if it is both or just yahoo. PLease advise. Thank you